# Not able to write proper function in asp.net mvc 3.0

Tags: c#

i have one method and it will **return IQueryable value**

```
public IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> Query(Expression<Func<TabMaster, bool>> whereCondition)
{
    IQueryable<TabMaster> tabmasters = _tabmasterRepository.GetQueryable().Where(whereCondition);
    IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> tabmasterview;
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TabMaster, TabMasterViewModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.colID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.colID));
    tabmasterview = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(tabmasters, tabmasterview);
    return tabmasterview;
}
```

and the **GetQueryable** is like

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable()
{
    return this.ObjectSet.AsQueryable<T>();
}
```

but the following line

```
tabmasterview = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(tabmasters, tabmasterview);
```

is giving me an **error**

Use of unassigned local variable 'tabmasterview'

*please suggest me, where is am i wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the compiler error all you have to do is

```
 IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> tabmasterview = null;
```

But the second argument you are passing to `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(tabmasters, tabmasterview)` is always null as tabMasterview has not been intialized. If that is intended you could as well pass "null".

```
public IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> Query(Expression<Func<TabMaster, bool>> whereCondition)
        {
            IQueryable<TabMaster> tabmasters = _tabmasterRepository.GetQueryable().Where(whereCondition);

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TabMaster, TabMasterViewModel>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.colID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.colID));
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IQueryable<TabMaster>,  IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel>> (tabmasters);            
        }
```

EDIT:

The above code answers your question related to compiler error.
As for your comments about the runtime error.. modify this line

```
return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IQueryable<TabMaster>,  IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel>> (tabmasters);
```

to

```
return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IQueryable<TabMaster>,  IEnumerable<TabMasterViewModel>> (tabmasters).AsQueryable<TabMasterViewModel>();
```

Comment: runtime error like: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.TabMasterViewModel]' to type 'Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.TabMasterViewModel]'. my updated code like 'public IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> 
IQueryable<TabMaster> tabmasters = _tabmasterRepository.GetQueryable().Where(whereCondition);
IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> tabmasterview = null;
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TabMaster, TabMasterViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.colID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.colID));
tabmasterview = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(tabmasters, tabmasterview);
return tabmasterview;

Comment: Yes. Check the updated code. Basically you are asking the AutoMapper to map an IQuerable of TabMaster's to Iquerable TabMasterViewModel.

Comment: **same error comes again:** Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CAFM.Business.Models.TabMasterViewModel]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CAFM.Business.Models.TabMasterViewModel]'.

Comment: I'd added code under edit section which should solve the run-time issue.

Comment: Hi dude you are absolutely right and now i am getting 100% success. Thanks a lot. my vote is +1